# How to change/assign the auto generated Enrollment ID to specific persons name in microsoft azure cognitive speaker identification API

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying the Microsoft Speaker Identification API. There are 3 steps

1. In the first step, we create profiles with auto-generated ID.
2. Then We enroll that ID with a specific voice.
3. We test the new audio file with enrolled IDs.

**My problem is instead of IDs are we able to give the specific name ex. John instead of Some ID:9557abdc-b9f4-4536-p530-a970e4d7a3d8. So for testing, it will generate output like "The speaker is john" or "The speaker is anonymous i.e. he is not enrolled"**

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a name to the `identificationProfileId`.

The `Create Profile` [endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c068e597ed22ec38f42e) does not accept any parameters other than the locale for the voice.

```
{
  "locale":"en-us",
}
```

> A complete supported locale list is here:
>
> - **es-ES (Castilian Spanish)**
> - **en-US (American English)**
> - **fr-FR (Standard French)**
> - **zh-CN (Mandarin Chinese)**

That being said, you can for example link user names to their designated `identificationProfileId` from your side, maybe using a database, and give each ID a corresponding name in a table, then return that with each API call.

Comment: Help me i am facing issue in this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525533/microsoft-cognitive-services-speaker-recognition-api-identification-error

Comment: @AkashDixit sure, I answered your question there :)