# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Speaker Recognition API - Identification - error

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services, voice-recognition

In this API I had successfully created Identification Profile, as well as created enrollment successfully and checked the operation status and received successfully enrolled.

Now I am trying to identify speaker but I am getting 
an error : 
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Audio too long"}}'
b'{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Audio too short"}}'

I tried various voice samples with different sizes like 5-Second, 10-Second, 15-Second, 30-Second, 40-Seconds, 80-Seconds. 
**And also mentioned identificationProfileIds should be as strings (How to do that)**

**For audio Recording, I am using $rec -c 1 -r 16000 -b 16 xa.wav**

But still getting the same errors I hope there might be some problem in my code. 
Please Help me 
If you can provide me the **code for Speaker - Identification** it will be so much helpful

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error, base64
subscription_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
}

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    # 'shortAudio': 'false',
    "identificationProfileIds":"080d22d6-917e-487f-a553-fb13a0575067",
 })


try:
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('speaker-recognition-api.cognitiveservices.azure.com')
    body = open('xa.wav','rb')
    #aud = base64.b64encode(body.read())
    print(body)
    conn.request("POST", "/spid/v1.0/identify?identificationProfileIds=080d22d6-917e-487f-a553-fb13a0575067&%s" % params, body, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(response)
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Speaker Recognition Python sample app as start and work from there, which you can find publicly available on GitHub by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Python)

You'll have to set your values in place in the respective files and particularly look for [IdentifyFile.py](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-SpeakerRecognition-Python/blob/master/Identification/IdentifyFile.py)

```
import IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper
import sys

def identify_file(subscription_key, file_path, force_short_audio, profile_ids):
    """Identify an audio file on the server.

    Arguments:
    subscription_key -- the subscription key string
    file_path -- the audio file path for identification
    profile_ids -- an array of test profile IDs strings
    force_short_audio -- waive the recommended minimum audio limit needed for enrollment
    """
    helper = IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper.IdentificationServiceHttpClientHelper(
        subscription_key)

    identification_response = helper.identify_file(
        file_path, profile_ids,
        force_short_audio.lower() == "true")

    print('Identified Speaker = {0}'.format(identification_response.get_identified_profile_id()))
    print('Confidence = {0}'.format(identification_response.get_confidence()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 5:
        print('Usage: python IdentifyFile.py <subscription_key> <identification_file_path>'
              ' <profile_ids>...')
        print('\t<subscription_key> is the subscription key for the service')
        print('\t<identification_file_path> is the audio file path for identification')
        print('\t<force_short_audio> True/False waives the recommended minimum audio limit needed '
              'for enrollment')
        print('\t<profile_ids> the profile IDs for the profiles to identify the audio from.')
        sys.exit('Error: Incorrect Usage.')

    identify_file(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4:])
```